# cross compiling using visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio

I compiled a x64 application in win32 development environment.. When I run that binary in 64 bit intel machine , the following error is displayed

"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."..

In the event log it is mentioned that

"Activation context generation failed for . Dependent Assembly icrosoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

What is this issue and how to resolve this problem ?and architecture of the target system is amd64.

```
C:\>set | findstr /i amd64
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates, that you are trying to run a debug build on a machine that has no debug C runtime installed. The debug runtime is not redistributable, so your current application will only run on a machine with VS2005 installed.

To fix this issue, change the build flavour from Debug to Release and try again.

You also need to make sure, the lates C runtime  libraries are available on the target machine. [This page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=766a6af7-ec73-40ff-b072-9112bab119c2&displaylang=en) holds the lates VS2005 redistributable runtime installers for all supportet target platforms .